# Exploring the uses of anonymous subs

Tags: perl

I've always been somewhat confused about the purpose and usage of anonymous subs in perl. I understand the concept, but looking for examples and explanations on the value of this practice.

To be clear:

```
sub foo { ... }   # <--- named sub
sub { ... }       # <--- anonymous sub
```

For example:

```
$ perl -e 'print sub { 1 }'
CODE(0xa4ab6c)
```

Tells me that sub returns a scalar value. So, I can do:

```
$ perl -e '$a = sub { 1 }; print $a'
```

For the same output as above. This of course holds true for all scalar values, so you can load arrays or hashes with anonymous subs.

The question is, how do I use these subs? Why would I want to use them?

And for a gold star, is there any problem which can only be resolved with an anonymous sub?

Comment: "And for a gold star, is there any problem which can only be resolved with an anonymous sub?" Nope. Where's my gold star? :P

Comment: More examples than you can shake a stick at: http://hop.perl.plover.com/

Comment: @Chris It's in the mail.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Anonymous subroutines can be used for all sorts of things.

1. Callbacks for event handling systems:

   ```
   my $obj = Some::Obj->new;

   $obj->on_event(sub {...});
   ```
2. Iterators:

   ```
   sub stream {my $args = \@_; sub {shift @$args}}

   my $s = stream 1, 2, 3;

   say $s->(); # 1
   say $s->(); # 2
   ```
3. Higher Order Functions:

   ```
   sub apply (&@) {
       my $code = shift;
       $code->() for my @ret = @_;
       @ret
   }

   my @clean = apply {s/\W+/_/g} 'some string', 'another string.';

   say $clean[0]; #  'some_string'
   ```
4. Creating aliased arrays:

   ```
   my $alias = sub {\@_}->(my $x, my $y);

   $alias[0]++;
   $alias[1] = 5;

   say "$x $y";  # '1 5''
   ```
5. Dynamic programming with closures (such as creating a bunch of subroutines that only differ by a small amount):

   ```
   for my $name (qw(list of names)) {
       no strict 'refs';
       *$name = sub {... something_with($name) ...};
   }
   ```

There is no situation where an anonymous subroutine can do anything that a named subroutine can not.  The `my $ref = sub {...}` constructor is equivalent to the following:

```
sub throw_away_name {...}

my $ref = \&throw_away_name;
```

without having to bother with deciding on a unique 'throw_away_name' for each sub.

The equivalence also goes the other way, with `sub name {...}` being equivalent to:

```
 BEGIN {*name = sub {...}}
```

So other than the name, the code reference created by either method is the same.

To call a subroutine reference, you can use any of the following:

```
 $code->();         # calls with no args
 $code->(1, 2, 3);  # calls with args (1, 2, 3)
 &$code();          # calls with no args
 &$code;            # calls with whatever @_ currently is
```

You can even use code references as methods on blessed or unblessed scalars:

```
 my $list = sub {@{ $_[0] }};

 say for [1 .. 10]->$list  # which prints 1 .. 10
```

Comment: A warning I encountered today seems to indicate there _is_ something an anonymous subroutine can handle that a named one won't always do correctly:  `Variable "%s" will not stay shared at ...`

Answer (score 8):

You can use it to create iterators.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.012;

sub fib_it {
  my ($m, $n) = (0, 0);

  return sub {
    my $val = ( $m + $n );
    $val = 1 unless $val;
    ($m, $n) = ($n, $val);
    return $val;
  }
}

my $fibber = fib_it;
say $fibber->() for (1..3); ### 1 1 2

my $fibber2 = fib_it;
say $fibber2->() for (1..5); ### 1 1 2 3 5
say $fibber->() for (1..3); #### 3 5 8
```

Comment: +1 A good, but somewhat hard to grasp explanation and example. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Anonymous subroutines can be used to create closures.

Closure is a notion out of the Lisp world that says if you define an anonymous function in a particular lexical context, it pretends to run in that context even when it's called outside the context.

- [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)
- [What's a closure?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#What%27s-a-closure?)

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: a minor nit, normal named subroutines can also be closures: `{my $x; sub count {$x++}}`.

Answer (score 7):

Here's something similar you might have seen before:

```
@new_list = map { $_ + 1 } @old_list;
```

And also:

```
@sorted = sort { $a <=> $b } @unsorted;
```

Neither of those are anonymous subs, but their behavior can be imitated in your functions with anonymous subs. They don't need the `sub` keyword because the functions are (essentially) prototyped to have their first argument be a subroutine, and Perl recognizes that as a special case where `sub` can be left off. (The functions also set the requisite variables to meaningful values before calling the subroutines you provided in order to simplify argument passing, but that's not related.)

You can write your own `map`-like function:

```
sub mapgrep (&@) { # make changes and also filter based on defined-ness
  my ($func, @list) = @_;
  my @new;
  for my $i (@list) {
    my $j = $func->($i);
    push @new, $j if defined $j;
  }
}
```

The magic to make it work with $_ is a bit much to write here - the above version only works for subs that take arguments.

Comment: if the first example would be like an anonymous sub, adding a `return` would not terminate the function, but only the `map`. Try                      sub foo {
  my @old_list = (1 .. 3);
  my @new_list = map { return $_ + 1 } @old_list;
  print "end of foo\n";
}

foo();
print "end\n";

Comment: "Both of those are anonymous subs." No, they aren't. See hexcoder's comment. They are anonymous code blocks that are `eval`ed, not called.

Comment: I thought in that context (map/sort) they were called blocks. I tried using the sub keyword in that context, and it was a syntax error.

Comment: @TLP - You're right. The `perlsub` page lists `&` as the way to accomplish this, even giving `sub mygrep (&@)` as a way to "write your own grep-like function" but then later notes that grep is not overloadable, presumably because of it's aforementioned block semantics. `&` as the first character in a prototype _does_ allow you to use the `func { ... }` syntax; however, some effort is required to make $_ (or $a and $b) work as "expected" for a grep-like function. See `List::Util::reduce`.

Answer (score 4):

Well I wrote a SAX parser for perl that is event driven.  You can pass anonymous subs to the begin/end events on an element.

```
my $str = "<xml><row><data></data></row></xml>":

my $parser = SAXParser->new();

$parser->when('row')->begin(sub {
    my ($element) = @_;
    push(@rows, $row);
});

$parser->when('row')->end(sub {
   ## do something like serialize it or whatever
});

$parser->parse($str);
```

Answer (score 3):

They are generally used when you want to pass a sub to another bit of code. Often this is a case of "When X happens (in third party code) do Y".

For example. When defining an attribute in [Moose](http://www.iinteractive.com/moose/about.html), you can specify the default value of that attribute using a sub. Given a class which has, as part of its definition:

```
  has 'size' => (
      is => 'ro',
      default =>
          sub { ( 'small', 'medium', 'large' )[ int( rand 3 ) ] },
      predicate => 'has_size',
  );
```

Whenever an instance of that class is created without an explicit size being passed, the sub will be called and the return value will be the size for that object.

If we switch to another language to give a different example, you'll find a similar concept in JavaScript.

```
var b = document.getElementById('my_button').
b.addEventListener('click', function (e) { alert('clicked!'); });
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you haven't actually **called** created subroutine. Call is performed with either &$a or $a->() syntax. What you've done is that you stored a **reference** to subroutine in $a, then stringifyed it and printed result. Compare:

```
my $a = sub {1};
my $b = sub {1};
print join("\n", $a, $a->(), $b, $b->());
```

Answer (score 2):

These are subs for the lazy programmer. You can use them for local throw-away functions and can save some typing. Instead of

```
sub x { ... }
my $function_ptr = \&x;
```

you can now use

```
my $function_ptr = sub { ... };
```

The anonymous functions are also private, and can only be accessed through the `$function_ptr`, so they don't have an entry in the symbol table.